# React web application proxy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, kubernetes, proxy

I am creating a simple web application. I have a problem, in the App.js file I have a function called Submit which calls a POST function with AXIOS when i press a button

```
 componentDidMount() {
   axios.get("/get")
     .then((response) => {
       this.setState({
         fetchData: response.data
       })
     })
     //this.Get().then((response)=>{ console.log("sono qui")})


 }

 submit = () => {
 axios.post(`/insert`, this.state)
     .then(() => { alert('success post') })
   console.log(this.state)
   document.location.reload()

 }
```

I have another file called setupProxy.js where I direct these calls to the server

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
     
    module.exports = function(app) {
        app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/get', { target: "http://localhost:3001" }));
        app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/insert', { target: "http://localhost:3001"}));
    };
```

The problem is that the server fails to enter the POST call while the GET call manages to enter quietly. Where am I wrong?

```
  app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/insert',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body.setBookName);
    let options = {
      url: 'http://backend.default.svc.cluster.local',
      form: {
        setBookName:this.state.setBookName , 
        setReview: this.state.setReview
      }
  };
    request.post(options);
})
app.get('/get',(req,res)=>{
  console.log("Entro");
  request.get("http://get-server.default.svc.cluster.local").pipe(res);
})
app.listen('3001', () => {console.log("Listening") })
```

Comment: Hi Fainol, It helps if you can include some information about what happens for the failed requests. Any errors or absence of errors. What response does the browser get for the request etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `app.post` code doesn't generate a response for the client.

```
   request.post(options);
```

Maybe you need to `pipe` the response like the `.get` request?

```
   request.post(options).pipe(res);
```